# Complex telemetry visualization and processing

Tags: azure-iot-central

I have several IoT devices (code is Java) that are in turn connected to several units locally. Each of these units reports data to the IoT device, and the IoT device publishes all the data in a variable array of nested objects, which also have arrays:

```
{
  "data":{
  "version":"1.2.3",
  "sensorData":{
     "a":18.50733137829912,
     "b":8.165982404692084,
     "c":20.75894428152493,
  },
  "units":[
     {
        "address":"192.168.254.16",
        "name":"Unit 1",
        "connectors":[
           {
              "id":1,
              "measurement":{
                 "a":13.44,
                 "b":0.0,
                 "c":0.0
              },
              "status":"running"               
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "address":"192.168.254.17",
        "name":"Unit 2",
        "connectors":[
           {
              "id":1,
              "measurement":{
                 "a":0.0,
                 "b":0.0,
                 "c":0.0
              },
              "status":"initialized",
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
 },
   "notificationType":"Status",
   "type":"Notification"
 }
```

Ideally I want to be able to go on some dashboard application like the Contoso example and click on this IoT device, and view a graph showing a,b,c on the sensorData, which is flat and fixed, but also show "Unit 1" and "Unit 2" separately as curves, as for example "Unit 1 - a", "Unit 1 - b", "Unit 1 - c", or aggregate them into a sum as "Unit 1 - total". Is this possible with the data presented?

[image: Example]

So, do I

- Post this data "as is" and somehow use a notation to get the nested data and aggregate?
- Process it on the IoT device to flatten it, like unit1_name, unit1_address, unit1_connector_1_a, unit1_connector_1_b, unit1_connector_1_c etc.
- Post this data "as is" and process/flatten the data in azure the same way as I would locally before it reaches the application (through stream analytics?)

All the samples I've seen has "flat" structure like a temperature and pressure on the root json object, so I am not sure what the best way to go forward here.

How does this fit into Application Insights? I also have events like "started", "stopped" etc, should I use the telemetry client for this (in Application Insights for Java)? What about logging? Using log4j2. Everything goes through DeviceClient and then is analyzed and distributed further thru Stream Analytics?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IoT Central currently supports only flat JSON for device measurements. So flatten the JSON on the device when forming the payload to post to IoT Hub. For events like "started", "stopped" you can use [State measurement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/howto-set-up-template#measurements).

Azure IoT Central is a different product than Application Insights. Application Insights' primary focus is on application/user monitoring whereas IoT Central is solely focused on IoT scenarios and has a completely different stack.